# "Good" resolution for calculating Ext and Tor

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I am studying homological algebra. Recently, I learned a free resolution called the bar construction, namely,
$$
\to\mathrm{bar}_{i}(A,M)\to\cdots\to M\to 0
$$
where $k$ is a ground field, $A=k\oplus A_{+}$ is a $k$-algebra, $M$ is a left $A$-module and $\text{bar}_{i}(A,M)=A\otimes_k A_{+}^{\otimes_k i}\otimes_k M$. I found it very useful when studying $\mathrm{Ext}_A^i(M,N)$ and $\mathrm{Tor}_i^A(M,N)$.

Now, I have a question. Are there any other "good" or "standard" resolutions (projective/free/injective/flat) for calculating Ext and Tor? Maybe we cannot use the bar resolution when we study a module over a ring (because a module over a ring does not necessarily have its basis). I would like to know many other useful resolutions if there are any.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you ever looked at Macaulay2? It can do explicit computations of Tor and Ext if you have a nice enough presentation of your ring, say as a polynomial ring over $\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{R}$, or $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have never used Macaulay2. It seems interesting. I will try to compute for some concrete cases.

Comment: The Bar resolution is useful in theory, but for computational purposes it is moot.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how general you want to go there are different answers.

- Calculate Ext, Tor for modules over a commutative unitary ring: The category of modules has both enough injectives and projectives, so you can use those
- Caclulate Ext, Tor for sheaves. Sheaves on a topological space have enough injectives, but not necessarily enough projectives. You can use the injectives for Ext, but for Tor you have to look elsewhere. The "correct" type of resolution is called flat resolution. I believe the best treatment to be via Cotorsion pairs as done by [Gillespie](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-07/S0002-9947-06-04157-2/S0002-9947-06-04157-2.pdf).
- Calculate Ext and Tor for complexes. One can generalize injectives and projectives to complexes, but there are some complications. One uses K-injectives or K-projective complexes to compute hypercohomology in this case. In the case of sheaves there are K-flat complexes. [Spaltenstein](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1988__65_2_121_0.pdf) has the details